# jsonschema python string encoded for error message

Tags: python, pyramid, jsonschema

When using jsonschema to validate some json the error message prepends **u** to all the keys. Can this be avoided?

```
json = request.json_body
```

---

```
errors = jsonValidator.iter_errors(json)
```

---

Then `error.message` is

```
"{u'data': [{u'y': u'ho', u'x': u'2000-04-23'}, {u'y': 2, u'x': u'2000-04-24'}, {u'y': 4, u'x': u'2000-04-25'}], u'updated': u'2012-05-29T18:25:43.511Z', u'created': u'2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z', u'user_id': u'1', u'title': u'Velocity vs Time upon blah blah'} is not of type 'array'"
```

Comment: It looks like it's returning a `dict` and somewhere along the line the `dict` is being fed to `str`.. did you mean to convert it to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u` indicates that the key strings are encoded in Unicode. It's unlikely that this will cause any problems - `u'data'` is functionally equivalent to `'data'` for your purposes, I would think.

Following on from your comment, you could use a simple string replacement operation to replace `u'` with `'`:

`error.message.replace('u\'', '\'')`

Comment: You can use a `string.replace` method to replace `u'` with `'` as per edited answer above.